# Laravel Query builder: Take and limit methods

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I dont undertand how these methods work, I'm trying to get last records inserted in my db and for this, I need a query builder so I made y consult with something like this:

```
 $costo = Costo_promedio::where('producto_nombre_id',$id_prod->id)->latest()->take(1);
```

The thing is I'm still getting all records inserted, in these methods `take` or `limit` I send the paramether of how many i want to get, and my question is. Why does this happen??

And no, I dont want to use the first() or get() methods these dont work when you do server side processing in a datattable

Answer (score 1):

`first()` is not return Collection. It returns a Model instance. Maybe you are not clear about Collection vs Model instance.

```
$costo = Costo_promedio::where('producto_nombre_id',$id_prod->id)->latest()->first();
```

---

Alternative:

```
$costo = Costo_promedio::where('producto_nombre_id',$id_prod->id)->latest()->get();

// $costo[0]
```

Comment: It returns a collection which i dont need :(, I'm working with datatables and I need a query builer structure

Comment: is `$costo[0]` a collection?

Comment: By the way `first()` not return collection..it return model instance..maybe you are not clear about Collection vs Model instance.. @Christian

Comment: Yeah srry I confused get() and first() methods, the thing is that these ones are not necessary when you do a server side procesing for a dattable, they dont return the correct data structure

Answer (score 1):

`take(1)` or `limit(1)` just adds `limit 1` to the query in builder. You need to call `get()` to fetch the results and it will return a `Collection` and you can get its only element by calling `first()` on it.

```
$costo = Costo_promedio::where('producto_nombre_id',$id_prod->id)->latest()->take(1)->get()->first();
```

Or you can replace `take(1)->get()->first()` with just `first()`

```
$costo = Costo_promedio::where('producto_nombre_id',$id_prod->id)->latest()->first()
```

`first()` will add `limit 1` and fetch the results and return the only item that's there

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$costo = Costo_promedio::orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(3)->get();
```

That Will get the last three records from the database assuming that your timestamp is named **created_at**.